# DocumentInteractionController Navigation Bar Color

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uidocumentinteraction

In my iOS application, I am using the DocumentInteractionController to preview the .csv document.

```
    self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileLocation];
    [self.documentController setDelegate:self];
    [self.documentController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

However, I am finding that the navigation bar is completely transparent. The back button is white, so it is not visible due to the white background.

[image]

Note that I have styled the navigation bar in the AppDelegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:138/255.0f blue:188/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINPro-Bold" size:17]}];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shadow"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
```

Essentially, my question is how can I make the appearance of the navigation bar in the DocumentInteractionController View Controller consistent with the appearance of the navigation bar throughout the entire app (or at least visible!).

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how other navigation bars appear?

Comment: What do you return for the method `– documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line puts a transparent (or rather void) background image to your UINavigationBar. Why is that?

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Just remove the line and everything works well.

If you want to set a shadow image, then you should think about using `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` instead of `appearance` so it won't spread to unhandled controllers.

As for the Status Bar Style, the simplest way would be to pass `self.navigationController` as the presenter, instead of self:

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
  return self.navigationController;
}
```

Hope this will help,

Comment: Thanks for the response! As it turns out, this line was causing the issue, but the reason why I did it was so that I could create a white separator by setting the shadow image. If that's the case, would you recommend creating a new background image with the separator instead? The title, unfortunately, is still black, even though I set the status bar style to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent.

Comment: Is there any way for me to get the shadow to show up without [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];?

Comment: Nope, see Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uinavigationbar_class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

Comment: I ended up using a regular wallpaper for the navigation bar. Thanks!